# PHP bug? Two functions with different names announced as redeclaration

Tags: php

I need to declare two functions with different names (small 'i' and big "I").

```
function i() {
    echo 'Small i';
}

function I() {
    echo 'Big I';
}
```

PHP's output is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare I()
```

Why? Small "i" is not big "I".

I tested it in Linux and in Windows.

Comment: As far as PHP function names are concerned, `i` *is* the same as `I`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php `Note: Function names are case-insensitive`...

Comment: apart from that having such similar function names would lead to a horrible dx (developer experience)

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions.

> Note: Function names are **case-insensitive**, though it is usually good
>   form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php